# ASA INSIDE to INSIDE traffic being dropped

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

An ASA 5505 is being used to route between two networks as it contains routes to everything.  The following depicts the network topology.

[image]

I have tried various combinations of access lists such as:

```
access-list INSIDE_TO_INSIDE extended permit ip any any
```

or

```
access-list INSIDE_TO_INSIDE extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

As well as:

```
 access-group INSIDE_TO_INSIDE in interface inside
```

I can not ping or connect from a PC on the .30 network to one on the .10 network.

My logs have things like:

```
    iscoasa# %ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-3-106014: Deny inbound icmp src inside:192.168.10.117 dst inside:192.168.30.11 (type 0, code 0)
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-3-106014: Deny inbound icmp src inside:192.168.10.117 dst inside:192.168.30.11 (type 0, code 0)
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64338 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64339 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-3-106014: Deny inbound icmp src inside:192.168.10.117 dst inside:192.168.30.11 (type 0, code 0)
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/22 to 192.168.30.11/64337 flags SYN ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64338 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64339 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-3-106014: Deny inbound icmp src inside:192.168.10.117 dst inside:192.168.30.11 (type 0, code 0)
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/21 to 192.168.30.11/64340 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64338 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 192.168.10.117/80 to 192.168.30.11/64339 flags RST ACK  on interface inside
```

This is a pretty stock ASA config.  Also packet tracer shows icmp or tcp 22 traffic as DROPPED by implicit rule from 192.168.30.11 to 192.168.10.117.  What's the deal?

Comment: According the network map I see routing issue. Do you have ping from ASA to PC 192.168.30.11 ? Give me routing table from ASA? **'ciscoasa# show route'**

Comment: The default route on the router is 192.168.10.5 (the ASA).  There is a static route from the ASA to the 192.168.30.0/24 network by the gateway 192.168.10.253.  The ASA can ping the PC on the 30 network\

Comment: If you put  gateway 192.168.10.253 for network 192.168.30.X on PC 192.168.10.117 then you will have access from 192.168.10.117 to 192.168.30.11. (**route add 192.168.30.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.253**) You know about it but you prefer to manage traffic between the two networks through ASA?

Comment: Yes I do prefer to do that and there are reasons (I am simulating a live environment).  The point is the routing is in place but the ASA for some reason is dropping INSIDE to INSIDE traffic.  It doesn't make sense.  It is even dropping pings which are stateless

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is
`same-security-traffic permit {inter-interface | intra-interface}`

By default, traffic entering one interface cannot exit the same interface.  The following command will allow this traffic.
`same-security-traffic permit intra-interface`

Often related to this command is the `same-security-traffic permit inter-interface` command.  By default, the ASA does not permit traffic from one security level to exit an interface of the same security level.  The `same-security-traffic permit inter-interface` command allows this traffic.

See this Cisco documentation for more details.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/refgd/s1.html